# How to I keep Intellij from arranging my static methods?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, code-formatting

I want to use Intellij to reformat code (whitespace) but without moving my  methods.

How do I disable  this? I tried unchecking everything in *Settings-> Editor-> CodeStyle-> Java ->Rearrange*, as follows, but still, all static methods are moved to the end.

[image: settings]

Comment: intelliJ idea uses intellisense to autosuggest methods or parameters.. Make sure you hit `ctrl+shift +Alt+L` in windows or `cmd+shift +Alt+L` ..

Comment: Ctrl-Shift-Alt-L (Ubuntu) gives the Reformat Code dialog. It does not let me configure how the code is reformatted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure rearrangement behavior in `Reformat Code` dialog (<kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Alt+L</kbd> shortcut).

Once dialog open, enable/disable [`Rearrange code`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/reformat-file-dialog.html) checkbox. If enabled, your source code entries should be redordered according to the configurations specified in the `Arrangement` tab of your [`Code Style`](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-code-style.html) settings.

Comment: OK, so the answer to my question is -- disable the Rearrange code checkbox

Comment: Doesnt seem to work. THere is no such checkbox. At least not anymore.